# getting MySQL ID from URL to display information on page

Tags: php, mysql, e-commerce

I have a products page where 8 product images are in a list which is being populated by images stored in a MySQL database. The images all have associated ID's in which a price, product name, and description is also associated with the same ID.

The idea behind what I am trying to do is; When a user clicks on one of the 8 product images, they will be redirected to a "checkout" page which will display the same image, plus all the information that is also stored under that ID in the database.

As of right now, I have the checkout page URL including the ID of the image (url.com/checkout.php?id=1) and I was hoping to find a way to get all the information stored under that ID in the URL to be displayed where called on the page.

Here is my php code that displays the images in the list on the products page:

```
    // Grab the data from our template table 
            $sql = "select * from templates"; 
            $result = mysql_query($sql) or die ("Could not access DB: " . mysql_error()); 
            while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) 
            { 
                echo "<li>"; 
                echo "<a class=\"caption\" href=\"purchase.php?id=\"" . $row['id'] . ">"; 
                // Note that we are building our src string using the ID from the database 
                echo "<img src=\"http://URL-REMOVED.com/file_display.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\" />"; 
                echo "<span>"; 
                echo "<big>" . $row['name'] . "</big>"; 
                echo $row['description']; 
                echo "</span>"; 
                echo "</a>"; 
                echo "</li>"; 

            }
```

Here is the php code that is supposed to gather the information of the clicked product (but doesn't):

```
    if (isset($_GET['id'])) 
        $id=$_GET['id']; 
    else 
         $id=1; 

    if (isset($_GET['action'])) 
        $action=$_GET['action']; 
     else 
        $action="empty"; 


    switch($action){ 

        case "add": 

        if($_SESSION['cart'][$id]) 
           $_SESSION['cart'][$id]++; 
        else 
            $_SESSION['cart'][$id]=1; 

         break;     

        case "remove": 

        if($_SESSION['cart'][$id]) 
       { 
           $_SESSION['cart'][$id]--; 

           if($_SESSION['cart'][$id]==0) 
    unset($_SESSION['cart'][$id]); 
           } 

          break;     

          case "empty": 
         unset($_SESSION['cart']); 

         break;     
         } 

 //Display Cart 

      if(isset($_SESSION['cart'])) { 

            $total=0; 
            foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $x) { 
            $result=mysql_query("select image,name,price,description from templates WHERE id=$id"); 
            $myrow=mysql_fetch_array($result); 
            $image=$myrow['image']; 
            $name=$myrow['name']; 
            $price=$myrow['price']; 
            $description=$myrow['description']; 

      }  
    }
```

And here is the actual HTML/PHP where the information is supposed to be displayed:

```
  <a class="caption" href="checkout.php"> 
            <img src="http://URL-REMOVED.com/file_display.php?id=<?php $myrow['id'] ?>"/> 
            <span> 
                <big> 
                    <strong><?php $myrow['name'] ?></strong> 
                </big> 

                <div class="price"><?php $myrow['price'] ?></div> 
            </span> 
        </a> 
    </div> 
    <div id="info_form_container"> 
    <div class="product_info"> 
        <div class="control-group"> 
            <strong>Template Name:</strong>  
            <?php $myrow['name'] ?> 
        </div> 

        <div class="control-group"> 
            <strong>Template Description:</strong> 
            <?php $myrow['description'] ?> 
        </div> 

        <div class="control-group"> 
            <strong>Template Price: </strong> 
            <?php $myrow['price'] ?> 
        </div> 
    </div>
```

I guess I'm not really sure if this is even the best method to take? But I definitely want to have the images stored in the database and I definitely want to call them using the ID...

How can I achieve this? Where am I wrong in my code?

Comment: check your tables, there might be nothing in your tables

Comment: New applications **SHOULD NOT USE** `mysql_query` but should be using one of the newer `mysqli` or PDO interfaces. [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) can lead to very serious problems. It's best you switch to one of these now before you create a giant mess you'll have to clean up.

Comment: okay, thanks for pointing that out. But that doesn't answer my question... And my tables are all full in my database.

Comment: Here are some links to documentation for [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) (supported as of PHP 5.1) and [mysqli](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) (supported as of PHP 4.1). If you're not sure which one to use, [read this article](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/pdo-vs-mysqli-which-should-you-use/).

Comment: thanks, but any suggestions on my actual question instead of critiquing my security?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDIT: I do not think I understood your question the first time. Try using this to generate your list of products, updating the connection information.  If this works, use the methods below to sanitize your variables and store your connection information elsewhere

```
<?php
    $mysqli_connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM templates"; 
    $result = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
    while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 

        $id = $row['id'];
        $name = $row['name'];
        $description = $row['description'];

        echo '<li>'; 
        echo '<a href="purchase.php?id='.$id.'" class="caption">'; 
        echo '<img src="http://URL-REMOVED.com/file_display.php?id='.$id.'" />'; 
        echo '<span>'; 
        echo '<big>'.$name.'</big>'; 
        echo $description; 
        echo '</span>'; 
        echo '</a>'; 
        echo '</li>';
    }
?>
```

OG Answer:

I think what you are doing is just fine.. It is the method I use (although mine seems a little neater).  Run your PHP functions to query your MySQL database using the ID you get, and just start dumping the information you get into your site.  To help with readability and cut down on spelling confusions, it might help to assign your `$myrow['whatever']` results into variables to echo out, but that is more cosmetic to me than anything.

To fix up your MySQL things and use mysqli, try out the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM templates"; 
$result = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
while ($row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC)) { 
    echo "<li>"; 
    echo "<a class=\"caption\" href=\"purchase.php?id=\"" . $row['id'] . ">"; 
    // Note that we are building our src string using the ID from the database 
    echo "<img src=\"http://URL-REMOVED.com/file_display.php?id=" . $row['id'] . "\" />"; 
    echo "<span>"; 
    echo "<big>" . $row['name'] . "</big>"; 
    echo $row['description']; 
    echo "</span>"; 
    echo "</a>"; 
    echo "</li>";
}
```

And try to sanitize your information using:

```
$my_stuff = mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['that_stuff']);
```

Also, you know you can use single quotes ('') around your echo statements if you want to, right?  May make it easier that escaping all of the double quotes..

So in full, this is probably a rough example of what I would do but I would split it up into functions and maybe create some global variables (such as the connection itself):

```
<?php


    $mysqli_connection = new mysqli("localhost", "username", "password", "database");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM templates WHERE id=$id"; 
    $result = $mysqli_connection->query($sql);
    // I'm assuming there is only one entry, so no while loop for me
    $row = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);

    $your_title = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['title']);
    $path_to_image = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['image']);
    $description = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['description']);
    $price = $mysqli_connection->real_escape_string($row['price']);

?>

<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>
        <h3><?php echo $your_title; ?></h3>
        <img src="<?php echo $path_to_image; ?>" />
        <ul>
            <li>Description: <?php echo $description; ?></li>
            <li>Price: <?php echo $price; ?></li>
            <!-- etc..-->
```

Comment: Thanks, but again, that is not the code I am having issues with. I cannot call the information from the selected ID onto the next page...

Comment: @TyBailey I edited my answer.  I think you are having problems because you need to echo out the values when the HTML is being rendered

Comment: I tried your method and it doesn't seem to work either. Im quite sure the issue is the ID is not being carried to the URL. It just adds the ?id= at the end of it with no ID #...

Comment: @TyBailey I updated my answer again, please check the edit and clarify where exactly the id is not showing up.  Is it in all places or specific places? What exactly does the source look like when you right-click and view the page source?

Comment: The final snippet is insecure and should be implementing a prepared statement to best handle the user-supplied data.