# How to pass value in php

Tags: php, html, sql

In my home page, I have a search bar with a button at the top of my page and I displayed all my songs using their title from my database underneath that.

The search bar is working fine since every song title I typed, it took me to the correct detail page.

I'm just wondering how can I also click on the song title and take me to each song detail page.

Home page

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$sql = 'SELECT title FROM song ORDER BY title ASC;';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['title' => $title]);
// fetch all rows
$songTitle = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


//Search bar

<form action="chord/details.php" method="post" class="p-3">
  <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary width =250px;" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary rounded-right">
            </div>
   </div>
</form>



// Here I display all my songs from the database using their title
<?php 
    foreach ($songTitle as $song) {

      // I'm not sure how to modify here.
     echo "<a href='chord/details.php'>{$song['title']} <br> </a>";
} ?>
```

Details page

```
//This is working fine with Search Bar
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $title = $_POST['search'];
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE title = :title';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['title' => $title]);
  $row = $stmt->fetch();

} else {
  header('location: .');
  exit();
}
?>

//Display the song lyrics here
<div>Original Key: <?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?></div><br>
<pre data-key=<?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?> id="pre">
              <?= ucfirst($row['lyrics']) ?>
</pre>
```

Comment: If you aren't actually adding any placeholders to a prepared statement, then there is nothing to bind -- so there shouldn't be any parameters fed into `execute()`.  If you have nothing to bind, then you don't need a prepared statement at all; just query normally without the overhead of a prepared statement.  You are effectly asking several questions. How to use `http_build_query()` to form a query string? and How to query your database for an id?  These are basic questions that have already been answered many times on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42833952/how-get-data-from-mysql-database-by-specific-id-in-url , https://stackoverflow.com/q/32462526/2943403

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12097334/getting-mysql-id-from-url-to-display-information-on-page , https://stackoverflow.com/q/41799274/2943403

Comment: "I'm not sure how to modify here." - what do you want to achieve? What have you tried so far? Is this a HTML problem, a PHP problem, or an SQL problem? I doubt that the problem itself is really related to all three technologies

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the get HTTP method to send the id of the song to the `details.php` page and query to the database on that id.

And it's always a good practice to use the `GET` HTTP method for searching actions. As `mickmackusa` said in the comment:

> $_POST is most appropriate when "writing" data server-side. $_GET is
> most appropriate when "reading" data server-side.

So change the code on the Home page as below:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
// query changed to fetch id as well
$sql = 'SELECT id , title FROM song ORDER BY title ASC;';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute(['title' => $title]);
// fetch all rows
$songTitle = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


<!-- here we change the method to get -->
<form action="chord/details.php" method="get" class="p-3">
  <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary width =250px;" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary rounded-right">
            </div>
   </div>
</form>


<?php 
    foreach ($songTitle as $song) {
        // we add the id to the link
        echo "<a href='chord/details.php?id={$song['id']}'>{$song['title']} <br> </a>";
    } 
?>
```

And change the `detail.php` like below:

```
<?PHP
//This is working fine with Search Bar
require_once '../config.php';

if (isset($_GET['search']) OR isset($_GET['id'])) {

    $condition = "";
    $value = "";
    if (!empty($_GET['id'])) {
        $condition = "id = :value";
        $value = $_GET['id'];
    }
    elseif (!empty($_GET['search'])) {
        $condition = "title = :value";
        $value = $_GET['search'];
    }

    $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE ' . $condition;
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
    $stmt->execute(['value' => $value]);
    $row = $stmt->fetch();


} else {
    header('location: .');
    exit();
}

?>

//Display the song lyrics here
<div>Original Key: <?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?></div><br>
<pre data-key=<?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?> id="pre">
              <?= ucfirst($row['lyrics']) ?>
</pre>
```

It's also a good idea to use `LIKE` for searching in the title like below:

```
if (!empty($_POST['search'])) {
    $condition = "title LIKE :value";
    $value = "%" . $_POST['search'] . "%";
}
```

Comment: `isset(..) and !empty(...)` is an antipattern that should not exist in any code for any reason. [Why check both isset() and !empty()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4559976/2943403)  To comply with PSR-12 coding standards, `else if` should always be `elseif`.  `$_POST` is most appropriate when "writing" data server-side.  `$_GET` is most appropriate when "reading" data server-side.  All of these actions are only reading, so `$_GET` should be used consistently.

Comment: @sajjadrezaei I just noticed that some reason my Search bar searching is not able to fetch anymore. any idea why it might be?

Comment: @mickmackusa yes I know `empty` check to be `isset` as well but I don't know I mostly check both, I think it's kind of an obsession for me. Thank you for your guide I update the answer.

Comment: @ziico Sorry my bad. I messed up with the keys in `detail.php` I did use the `submit` key as a value that I should use the `search` key. I update the answer based on comments.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have an `id` column in the `song` table. You could do something like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
$sql = 'SELECT id, title FROM song ORDER BY title ASC;';
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
// fetch all rows
$songTitle = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
?>


//Search bar

<form action="chord/details.php" method="post" class="p-3">
  <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="search" id="search" class="form-control form-control-lg rounded-0 border-primary width =250px;" placeholder="Search..." autocomplete="off" required>
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-primary rounded-right">
            </div>
   </div>
</form>



// Here I display all my songs from the database using their title
<?php 
    foreach ($songTitle as $song) {

      // I'm not sure how to modify here.
     echo "<a href='chord/details.php?id=".$song['id]."'>{$song['title']} <br> </a>";
} ?>
```

Details page

```
//This is working fine with Search Bar
<?php
require_once '../config.php';
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  $title = $_POST['search'];
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE title = :title';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['title' => $title]);
  $row = $stmt->fetch();

} elseif (!empty($_REQUEST['id'])) {
  $sql = 'SELECT * FROM song WHERE id = :id';
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute(['id' => $_REQUEST['id']]);
  $row = $stmt->fetch();
} else {
  header('location: .');
  exit();
}
?>

//Display the song lyrics here
<div>Original Key: <?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?></div><br>
<pre data-key=<?= ucfirst($row['chord']) ?> id="pre">
              <?= ucfirst($row['lyrics']) ?>
</pre>
```